# Calculate supremum of $\left|1-e^{-\gamma_n t}\right|$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Calculate *Sup* (Supremum) of:

$$\sup_n \left|1-e^{-\gamma_n t}\right|$$

and

$$\sup_n \left(e^{-\gamma_n t}\right)$$

where $|\gamma_n|\leq M$, $M \in \mathbb R^+$ and $\gamma_n\in \mathbb R$; t is a parameter such that $t\in [-\pi,\pi]$.

My solution.

$$\sup_n \left(e^{-\gamma_n t}\right)\leq e^{|L|}$$

because $e^{-x}$ is decreasing and L real constant (maybe $L=M\pi$?)

$$\sup_n \left|1-e^{-\gamma_n t}\right|\leq e^{|L|}-1$$

because, putting $y=|1-e^{-x}|$ and evaluating in $x=\pm h, h>0$ we have that $y_{h^-}>y_{h^+}$.

Is my procedure right? I made ​​a mistake?

thank you very much

Comment: there is an issue with the supremum over $n$, since it does not depend on $t$ we cannot determine whether $\gamma_nt$ is positive or negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems right but I think for:

$\sup_n(e^{-\gamma_nt})$, you need to argue the fact for $t\in[-\pi,\pi]$ there exists a $t^*=-sign(\gamma_n)\pi$, since then you can argue:

$\sup_n(e^{-\gamma_nt})\leq\sup_n(e^{-\gamma_nt^*})=\sup_n(e^{-(-sign(\gamma_n))\gamma_n\pi})=\sup_n(e^{sign(\gamma_n)\gamma_n\pi})=\sup_n(e^{|\gamma_n|\pi})=e^{M\pi}$.

Comment: Ok. This also applies to $\sup_n \left|1-e^{-\gamma_n t}\right|
$?

Comment: Yes it would :)